# parameterMappingInterceptor with annotated Spring Portlet MVC

Tags: java, spring, portlet, interceptor

I'm wondering if there's a way to simulate the parameterMappingInterceptor behavior if I'm not using a portletModeParameterHandlerMapping. Of course, I'm using the annotated approach. I've tried to define my portlet.xml like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
   xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
        http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr 
        http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="es.xunta.formacion.sifo3.economico.web.controllers"/>

<bean id="parameterMappingInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.portlet.handler.ParameterMappingInterceptor"/>  

</beans>
```

But apparently, this is not working at all, and I still need to set the action parameter in the render phase, to access the render methods:

```
@RequestMapping(params = "action=myAction")
public final void doAction(@ModelAttribute(value = "myAttribute") MyBean myBean, Errors errors, ActionRequest actionrequest, ActionResponse actionresponse) {
validateBean(escrituraBean, errors);
//..
actionresponse.setRenderParameter("action", actionrequest.getParameter("myAction"));
}

@RequestMapping(params = "action=myAction")
public final String doRender(ModelMap model, RenderRequest renderrequest) {
//..
}
```

Edit: I've also tried to configure the xml with this:

```
<bean id="annotationMapper" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
<property name="interceptors">
    <list>
                <bean id="parameterMappingInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.portlet.handler.ParameterMappingInterceptor"/>  
    </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

Obtaining this exception:

```
 Interceptor type not supported: org.springframework.web.portlet.handler.ParameterMappingInterceptor
```